# Getting X, Y and Z reference planes in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, 3d, plotly.js

I'm learning a bit of **plotly** mixing it with HTML/JavaScript, so I'm using the  **plotly.js** CDN

I pretend to draw a set of randomly generated dots into a `X`, `Y`, and `Z` coordinate space, I have successfully generated all the dots but I'm facing an issues trying to show in the same drawing all three coordinates axis as a reference planes...

I have successfully been able to show the **`XY`** plane and dots

[image]

But I'm still failing to shows the **`XZ`** and **`YZ`** references planes as I'm doing in here but with lines

[image]

I have even attempt to use *chatGPT* but it's totally lost trying to resolve the issue...

Here share the whole JS script code I'm using , hope I get someone that can help!!!!

```
<script>
    // Array to store the generated points
    const dots = [];

    // Generate 100 points with random x, y, z coordinates
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const x = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
      const y = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
      const z = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
      dots.push({ x, y, z });
    }

    // Extract x, y, and z coordinates separately for the chart
    const xData = dots.map(point => point.x);
    const yData = dots.map(point => point.y);
    const zData = dots.map(point => point.z);

    // Configure the 3D chart trace
    const trace = {
      x: xData,
      y: yData,
      z: zData,
      mode: 'markers',
      marker: {
        size: 5,
        color: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      },
      type: 'scatter3d',
    };

    // Plane x-y (z = 0)
    const dataPlaneXY = {
        x: [-10, 10, 10, -10], 
        y: [-10, -10, 10, 10], 
        z: [0, 0, 0, 0], 
        type: 'mesh3d',
        colorscale: 'Viridis', 
        opacity: 0.5, 
        lighting: {
            specular: 0.2,
            ambient: 0.8,
            diffuse: 0.5,
            fresnel: 0.2,
        },
    };

    // Plane x-z (y = 0)
    const dataPlaneXZ = {
        x: [-10, 10, 10, -10], 
        y: [0, 0, 0, 0], 
        z: [-10, -10, 10, 10], 
        type: 'mesh3d',
        colorscale: 'Viridis', 
        opacity: 0.5, 
        lighting: {
            specular: 0.2,
            ambient: 0.8,
            diffuse: 0.5,
            fresnel: 0.2,
        },
    };

    // Plane y-z (x = 0)
    const dataPlaneYZ = {
        x: [0, 0, 0, 0], 
        y: [-10, 10, 10, -10], 
        z: [-10, -10, 10, 10], 
        type: 'mesh3d',
        colorscale: 'Viridis', 
        opacity: 0.5, 
        lighting: {
            specular: 0.2,
            ambient: 0.8,
            diffuse: 0.5,
            fresnel: 0.2,
        },
    };

    // Data for the chart, including the lines for the reference planes
    const data = [trace, dataPlaneXY, dataPlaneXZ, dataPlaneYZ];

    // Configure the layout of the 3D chart
    const layout = {
      scene: {
        xaxis: { title: 'X Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
        yaxis: { title: 'Y Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
        zaxis: { title: 'Z Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
        aspectmode: 'cube', //  ensures the axes have the same scale
        showaxeslines: true, // Show axis lines
      },
    };
    // Draw the 3D chart
    Plotly.newPlot('coordinateChart', data, layout);
  </script>
```

---

Thanks a lot for **@kikon** for they answer  ( please read it!!! )

### If someone is interested here the result of his answer

[image]

Comment: I'm not allowed to create new tags so if anyone want to created them it will be grate to have [ alphahull ] and [ delaunayaxis ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `mesh3d` is a set of triangles; the properties `x`, `y` and `z` specify a set of points; one has also to specify how these points are to be grouped in triangles.

The safest and clearest way to do that is to set the properties [`i`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/mesh3d/#mesh3d-i), `j` and `k`.
If one sets:

```js
i: [0, 1],
j: [1, 2],
k: [2, 3],
```

there will be two triangles: the first formed by the points 0,1,2 and the second by points 1,2,3 - coordinates taken from the `x`,`y`,`z` arrays.

Here's a solution, based on that (note that I changed the order of two coordinates also):

```js
const dots = [];

// Generate 100 points with random x, y, z coordinates
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   const x = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
   const y = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
   const z = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
   dots.push({ x, y, z });
}

// Extract x, y, and z coordinates separately for the chart
const xData = dots.map(point => point.x);
const yData = dots.map(point => point.y);
const zData = dots.map(point => point.z);

// Configure the 3D chart trace
const trace = {
   x: xData,
   y: yData,
   z: zData,
   mode: 'markers',
   marker: {
      size: 5,
      color: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
   },
   type: 'scatter3d',
};

// Plane x-y (z = 0)
const dataPlaneXY = {
   x: [-10, 10, -10, 10],
   y: [-10, -10, 10, 10],
   z: [0, 0, 0, 0],
   i: [0, 1],
   j: [1, 2],
   k: [2, 3],
   type: 'mesh3d',
   colorscale: 'Viridis',
   opacity: 0.5,
   lighting: {
      specular: 0.2,
      ambient: 0.8,
      diffuse: 0.5,
      fresnel: 0.2,
   },
};

// Plane x-z (y = 0)
const dataPlaneXZ = {
   x: [-10, 10, -10, 10],
   y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
   z: [-10, -10, 10, 10],
   i: [0, 1],
   j: [1, 2],
   k: [2, 3],
   type: 'mesh3d',
   colorscale: 'Viridis',
   opacity: 0.5,
   lighting: {
      specular: 0.2,
      ambient: 0.8,
      diffuse: 0.5,
      fresnel: 0.2,
   },
};

// Plane y-z (x = 0)
const dataPlaneYZ = {
   x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
   y: [-10, 10, -10, 10],
   z: [-10, -10, 10, 10],
   i: [0, 1],
   j: [1, 2],
   k: [2, 3],
   type: 'mesh3d',
   colorscale: 'Viridis',
   opacity: 0.5,
   lighting: {
      specular: 0.2,
      ambient: 0.8,
      diffuse: 0.5,
      fresnel: 0.2,
   },
};

// Data for the chart, including the lines for the reference planes
const data = [trace, dataPlaneXY, dataPlaneXZ, dataPlaneYZ];

// Configure the layout of the 3D chart
const layout = {
   scene: {
      xaxis: { title: 'X Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
      yaxis: { title: 'Y Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
      zaxis: { title: 'Z Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
      aspectmode: 'cube', //  ensures the axes have the same scale
      showaxeslines: true, // Show axis lines
   },
};
// Draw the 3D chart
Plotly.newPlot('coordinateChart', data, layout);
```

```html
<div id='coordinateChart' style="height:450px; width:100%"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plotly.js/2.24.3/plotly.min.js" integrity="sha512-OB3KqMv8ZelkEhNOv1J6PB0aYRkn8oota0+LoGXIVD3hv1Pu9ebxFJXBopRlGkYLTLEUM7aX9zBepBzGcZzH5A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Now, for an alternative solution, and an explanation of why did the xy plane work without the `i`, `j`, `k`: if they are not specified, then the Delaunay triangulation is used - see the docs on [alphahull](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/mesh3d/#mesh3d-alphahull) and [delaunayaxis](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/mesh3d/#mesh3d-delaunayaxis) properties.

So, it turns out that at least for the 4 coplanar points that you have Delaunay triangulation works fine, but you have to set the `delaunayaxis` to the axis perpendicular to their plane. And yes, the default is `z` and that's why it worked with no addition for the xy plane:

```js
const dots = [];

// Generate 100 points with random x, y, z coordinates
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   const x = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
   const y = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
   const z = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
   dots.push({ x, y, z });
}

// Extract x, y, and z coordinates separately for the chart
const xData = dots.map(point => point.x);
const yData = dots.map(point => point.y);
const zData = dots.map(point => point.z);

// Configure the 3D chart trace
const trace = {
   x: xData,
   y: yData,
   z: zData,
   mode: 'markers',
   marker: {
      size: 5,
      color: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
   },
   type: 'scatter3d',
};

// Plane x-y (z = 0)
const dataPlaneXY = {
   x: [-10, 10, 10, -10],
   y: [-10, -10, 10, 10],
   z: [0, 0, 0, 0],
   delaunayaxis: 'z', //default
   type: 'mesh3d',
   colorscale: 'Viridis',
   opacity: 0.5,
   lighting: {
      specular: 0.2,
      ambient: 0.8,
      diffuse: 0.5,
      fresnel: 0.2,
   },
};

// Plane x-z (y = 0)
const dataPlaneXZ = {
   x: [-10, 10, 10, -10],
   y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
   z: [-10, -10, 10, 10],
   delaunayaxis: 'y',
   type: 'mesh3d',
   colorscale: 'Viridis',
   opacity: 0.5,
   lighting: {
      specular: 0.2,
      ambient: 0.8,
      diffuse: 0.5,
      fresnel: 0.2,
   },
};

// Plane y-z (x = 0)
const dataPlaneYZ = {
   x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
   y: [-10, 10, 10, -10],
   z: [-10, -10, 10, 10],
   delaunayaxis: 'x',
   type: 'mesh3d',
   colorscale: 'Viridis',
   opacity: 0.5,
   lighting: {
      specular: 0.2,
      ambient: 0.8,
      diffuse: 0.5,
      fresnel: 0.2,
   },
};

// Data for the chart, including the lines for the reference planes
const data = [trace, dataPlaneXY, dataPlaneXZ, dataPlaneYZ];

// Configure the layout of the 3D chart
const layout = {
   scene: {
      xaxis: { title: 'X Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
      yaxis: { title: 'Y Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
      zaxis: { title: 'Z Coordinate', range: [-10, 10], showaxeslines: true },
      aspectmode: 'cube', //  ensures the axes have the same scale
      showaxeslines: true, // Show axis lines
   },
};
// Draw the 3D chart
Plotly.newPlot('coordinateChart', data, layout);
```

```html
<div id='coordinateChart' style="height:450px"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plotly.js/2.24.3/plotly.min.js" integrity="sha512-OB3KqMv8ZelkEhNOv1J6PB0aYRkn8oota0+LoGXIVD3hv1Pu9ebxFJXBopRlGkYLTLEUM7aX9zBepBzGcZzH5A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! @kikon this work amazing I was totally ignoring that `mesh3d` references to a set of triangles so thanks I'll be reading the Links you shares!!!